# Saving image to PHP session

Tags: php, session, session-variables

**What I'm attempting to accomplish**

Hi! I've scoured the web and can't quite find what I'm looking for. We are working on an internal email signature creation tool. I would like to add an image to a session so I can insert that image into the tool at the end. **I do not want to store it in a temp folder or save it to a database**. I know this is not best practice to put images in a session. The tool copies all rendered HTML to your clipboard to be immediately inserted into Gmail/Outlook.

**My code on Page 1**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</form>
```

**My code on Page 2**

```
<?php
    $_SESSION["fileToUpload"] = $_POST['fileToUpload'];
?>
```

**The result**

[image]

"image.png" text is inserted into the signature tool. Instead of the file info/name inserted into the tool, I want the actual image itself. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: it is already stored in a temp folder, you dont need move it, you can just fetch its contents `$_SESSION["fileToUpload"] = file_get_contents($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"])` obviously need do validation and handle upload fails before that though

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tested the code but I'm getting a "Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty" on that line when I add it to page 2.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to do something like markdown? That's not going to work...
You could try this: 
https://github.com/ziggi/zimg-host

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an image to base64 encode and then play with it.

Example:

```
$img = file_get_contents('<path>/image.jpg'); 
$data = base64_encode($img);
```

As result, you will have a bit string that you can save the value in the session.

But keep in mind that this is not a best practice.

Also, you can use this string in the source of an image.

Example:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAyACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```